# Intel(R) Graphics (ADL-S Gt1) in i9 12900k

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, intel-graphics, intel-core-i9

I have two system with i9 12900k cpu, in windows when I run geekbench test it shows Intel(R) UHD Graphics 770 but in when I run it geekbench in my ubuntu system it shows Intel(R) Graphics (ADL-S GT1) but both of them have same cpu. Are both of the integrated gpu's same?

Comment: `ADL-S GT1` is an Intel Alder Lake GPU; Alder Lake is 13th generation not 12th generation, so you don't have identical systems with the same processor.

Comment: What is strange is `UHD Graphics 770` is based on the `ADL-S GT1` so they are one in the same.

Comment: I have exactly same system with i9 12900k so how it is showing different integrated graphics on different os

Comment: It likely comes down to however the driver identifies the GPU. They are the same chip